# Is there a CSS-way to make text grow column-wise horizontally

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I'm working for a client that had the super good idea to integrate a horizontal scroll effect into his one pager flow layout. That means that the user keeps scrolling down, but at some point the page starts moving from right to left instead of bottom to top. I implemented that via ScrollMagic.

So the problem starts when it gets responsive. When I start scrolling horizontally, the screen is now fixed to the device height and I need to extend my page content to the right when it flows out, instead of the normal "my content just flows out of the bottom, which I can follow by vertically scrolling".

My first idea was to kind of manually solve the problem when managing the content. I.E. giving different versions of content for mobile and desktop content. But it seems devices are just too different and I need a CSS solution.

My Question is: Do you have any idea of how to make content grow horizontally? Like height auto, but width "auto" (which doesn't work bc it's not the same)? Or like display: inline-block in the following example, but the outer wrapper (yellow border) wrapping all sub-boxes, not just the first column.

```css
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ffff00;
    
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

#main div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
After reading Temani Afifs Answer I found an additional specification of my problem: I need it to work with "column-width", so that I am able to write text which automatically expands to a second column when using up all vertical space. Pretty much just like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Handling_Overflow_in_Multicol#more_columns_than_will_fit). The only reason the linked example is not perfect for me is that the wrapping container div does not expand and a scrollbar appears. I want to be able to add another .container-div to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using CSS grid:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background:yellow;
}

#main {
  max-height: 100vh;  /* don't take more than the screen height */
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* column flow */
  /* fill all the column and wrap to the next one if no more space */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}

#main div {
  padding:20px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
    <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
    <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
    <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
    <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's already a good start. Unfortunately my situation is a bit more specific than I originally asked for: Do you think it would be possible to combine this with the "column-count" property? Imagine there was only the red "A"-Block, but with a long text. The desired behavior is the text going down to the screen bottom, only taking the left column space and then, with more text, expanding into the second column.